# How to escape a square bracket for Pattern compilation?

Tags: java, regex, escaping, special-characters

I have comma separated list of regular expressions:

```
.{8},[0-9],[^0-9A-Za-z ],[A-Z],[a-z]
```

I have done a *split* on the comma. Now I'm trying to match this regex against a generated password. The problem is that `Pattern.compile` does not like *square brackets* that is not escaped.

Can some please give me a simple function that takes a string like so: `[0-9]` and returns the escaped string `\[0-9\]`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`Pattern.quote(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-).

From the docs:

> `public static String quote​(String s)`
>
> Returns a literal pattern `String` for the specified `String`.
>
> This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

Comment: What value do you put in for `String`? `Pattern.quote("\[0-9\]")`?

Comment: @DannyBullis From the question "a simple function that takes a string like so: `[0-9]` and returns the escaped string `\[0-9\]`". So you'd give this `"[0-9]"`, and it will return something equivalent to `"\[0-9\]"`. (It actually uses `\Q` and `\E`, but the end result has the same effect when given to `Pattern.compile`.)

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the quick help, even 9 years later :)

Answer (score 52):

I was expecting a single backslash to escape the bracket, however, you must use two if you have the pattern stored in a string.  The first backslash escapes the second one into the string, so that what regex sees is `\]`.  Since regex just sees one backslash, it uses it to escape the square bracket.

```
\\]
```

In regex, that will match a single closing square bracket.

If you're trying to match a newline, for example though, you'd only use a single backslash.  You're using the string escape pattern to insert a newline character into the string.  Regex doesn't see `\n` - it sees the newline character, and matches that.  You need two backslashes because it's not a string escape sequence, it's a regex escape sequence.

Comment: When thinking about it I came up why this is like that: The regex is a String and whatever processes this regex will look for a single backslah as an escape character. However as the regex is passed as a String you have to escape the backslah as well in order to get it into a String properly and that's the readon why you need two backslashes

Answer (score 15):

You can use the \Q and \E special characters...anything between \Q and \E is automatically escaped.

```
\Q[0-9]\E
```

Comment: Sounds a bit perlish if you ask me, have you tried it in java (I havn't, that's why I ask).

Comment: It's valid in Java too: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html (ctrl-F for "\Q")

Comment: In Java string literal format it would be "\\Q[0-9]\\E" or "\\Q" + regex + "\\E".  But the quote() method does that for you, plus it deals correctly with strings that already have \E in them.

Answer (score 3):

`Pattern.compile()` likes square brackets just fine.  If you take the string

```
".{8},[0-9],[^0-9A-Za-z ],[A-Z],[a-z]"
```

and split it on commas, you end up with five perfectly valid regexes: the first one matches eight non-line-separator characters, the second matches an ASCII digit, and so on.  Unless you really want to match strings like `".{8}"` and `"[0-9]"`, I don't see why you would need to escape anything.