# Why can't I replace ":)"

Tags: java, regex, string

I can't seem to replace a string of ":)" to something else, here is my code:

```
if(message.contains(":)")) message = message.replaceAll(":)", replacement);
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "Listen" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')'
near index 0
:)
^
```

What should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279893/how-to-replace-brackets-in-strings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `replaceAll()`; use [`replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) when you want to replace literal strings:

```
message.replace(":)", replacement)
```

`replaceAll()` deals with [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), in which `)` has a special meaning, hence the error.

Comment: +1 I hate when ppl do that, downvoting with no comment espcially when they are wrong!

Comment: Why would someone downvote this?

Comment: BTW, `replace()` function is backed by Pattern class, not a normal loop append.

Answer (score 2):

You must escape `)` in regexen:

```
message = message.replaceAll(":\\)", replacement);
```

This is because `)` has special meaning (capture groups), so you have to "tell" regex that you just want a literal `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
message.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(":)"), replacement);
```

[`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) accept a regex, not a regular String. `)` has a special meaning in regex, using [`quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) will cause treating `:)` as the String `:)` and not the regex.

If you don't want to use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29), you should *escape* the `)` by `\\`. Note that escaping a regex is done by `\`, but in Java, `\` is written as `\\`.

If you don't like any of the mentioned, use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) that doesn't accept a regex, and you're fine.

Comment: God.... give someone opportunity to fix his mistake................

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Using a `#` is a common way to separate a class name and a method/property name when referencing a method/property (typically in docs).

Comment: @ajp15243 I know, but before the edit it was `message.replaceAll(Pattern#quote(":)"), replacement);` (now fixed)

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow Ah I see, well the question went through so many edits I didn't catch that lol.