# what regular expression can match the [ and ] characters?

Tags: java, regex, brackets

I'm trying to use  the java method replaceAll(), that removes from a string all characters that match a given regex, to remove the opening and closing brackets characters from a string.

So, I need to use as a parameter a regex that matches [ and ].

I've tried using [|] or ([|]) but they don't seem to work.

Comment: `\[` and `\]`.. This is so basic, it should be in any documentation.

Comment: It *is* in the documentation: "[abc]  a, b, or c (simple class)" and "\ [...] quotes the following character".

Comment: And since you're in Java, you will need to add an extra slash to escape the first slash. :)

Comment: In any language, if you need to use the literal representation of a special character, you have to escape it.

Comment: You can also use Pattern.quote to do the same if you feel like doing a little extra typing. See this question for even more sugar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140268/how-to-escape-a-square-bracket-for-pattern-compilation

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape them:

```
 \[ and \]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should take off both the opening and closing brackets for you.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
```